# Getting null Model from PostAsync Request

Tags: c#, .net, rest, microservices

I am making a communication between two microservices. I am trying to obtain the content from the model "UserBookPreference". I already debugged and the content that is being sent in the `PostAsync()` request is correct (let's say, data from microservice A). The problem arises when I try to receive the contents from the Post method in microservice B. The model type I have as parameter is the same I am sending from the postAsync. Since I am using .NET 5, the `JsonContent.Create()` method is a good approach according to my reasearch. I have tried other methodologies, such as using the `StringContent()` method but still I get the null object in microservice B. This is the code I am using.
In microservice A:

```
 public async Task<string> AddFavoriteBook(UserBookPreference bookModel)
        {
            JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(bookModel);
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URLHelper._baseUserPreferencesMicroserviceURL + "/Book", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
}
```

In microservice B:

```
[HttpPost("Favorites/Book")]
        public IActionResult AddUserFavoriteBook(UserBookPreference bookModel)
        {
            try
            {
                _prefService.AddUserBookFavorite(bookModel);
                return Ok(bookModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either add `[FromBody]` attribute before `UserBookPreference` in your endpoint or add a `[ApiController]` attribute to your controller to bind `UserBookPreference` to incoming body. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/#apicontroller-attribute)

Comment: My mistake: I had forgotten the [ApiController] attribute. Thank you for the reminder.